# How do you use SQLCMD to login to SQL Server Express, user no password set

Tags: sqlcmd

I installed SQL Server 2012 Express and I'm learning from a book on SQL Server administration. My task is to write a batch file to copy data from a table and export it to an Excel spreadsheet.

I've got the instance name right and my username but log in fails because of password. When I enter Management Studio and click connect I see my username but password is blank, I successfully connect to my databases this way. How do I set a password for my account? I think I can't log in using SQLCMD because I don't have this set. My username is the same as my windows username, using the password that I log on to windows with doesn't work.

```
SQLCMD -S CRAIG-PC\SQLExpress -U CRAIG-PC\Craig -P ********* 
       -d AdventureWorks 
       -Q "SELECT * FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail" -o C:\ExportDir\export.csv
```

This is the command in the batch file that I'm trying to connect and query the database. If I take out  `-P *******` SQL Server is waiting for a password. If I don't use a username or password connection is refused.

Remote connections are enabled using tcp, but this is a local install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the name of the database, ie "AdventureWorks" should be "AdventureWorks2012"

Answer (score 1):

Use the '-E' switch to make your connection a trusted (Window's authentication) one, then you don't need user name and password at all (provided you have sufficient rights on your machine)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx

Note in my python code below, I don't implement the user or password.

Hope that helps

```
    _query = "CREATE DATABASE %s ON (FILENAME = '%s'), (FILENAME = '%s') FOR ATTACH;" %(_database, mdffilepath, logfilepath)

    command_process = SubP.Popen(['sqlcmd','-b', '-E',
                              '-S', _server,
                              '-d', 'master',
                              '-q', _query],
                             stdin = SubP.PIPE,
                             stdout = SubP.PIPE, 
                             stderr = SubP.STDOUT, 
                             shell = True)

    _stdOut, _stdError = command_process.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you are using windows authentication you can remove the -u and -p. when those are not provided sqlcmd will use windows authentication.